# Razor / C# - How to render a page in a code block?

Tags: razor, rendering

I have two files in my root directory namely "test1.cshtml" and "test2.cshtml".

When I try to render `test2.cshtml` in `test1.cshtml`, it was successful, I used this code:

```
@RenderPage("~/test2.cshtml");
```

But when I try to render `test2.cshtml` in `test1.cshtml` using a code block, it wasn't rendered.

```
@{
    RenderPage("~/test2.cshtml");   
}
```

Additional Information:

`test2.cshtml` contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello WebMatrix
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RenderPage returns a string

The @code syntax you used first is desigened to run a statement and write the output to the output stream

The second syntax you used just executes code; (its a code block like you pointed out, and it can contain multiple statements). You discard the result of the RenderPage statement that way!

try:

```
@{
    var pageHtml = RenderPage("~/test2.cshtml");
}

@pageHtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
@{
    Response.Write(RenderPage("~/test2.cshtml"));
}
```

In case you want to pass data:

```
@{
    Response.Write(RenderPage("~/test2.cshtml", new{ Data1 = "Hello", Data2 = "World" }));
}
```

and to use the data,

```
.
.
<body>
    @Page.Data1 @Page.Data2
    @Model.Data1 @Model.Data2
</body>
.
.
```

Comment: There seems to be some concern with this approach as Response.Write seems to be called when the page is just loaded, causing the contents to be written out of context (at the beginning of the page).

Comment: @Rafid If your concern is about the data on the main page, see edit. If this is not your concern, please explain it to me so I can address it. Thank you!